# Reading a numpy array of strings in memmap mode

Tags: python, numpy

I created this numpy array and stored it in disk as follows:

```
s = (b'foo', b'bar', b'baz', b'buzz')
def build_numpy_array():
  return np.fromiter((s for _ in range(200)), dtype=[('foo','S40'), 
  ('bar', 'S40'), ('baz', 'S40'), 
  ('buzz', 'S40')
  ])

np.save('data.dat', {'data': build_numpy_array()})
```

This works fine
`np.load('data.dat.npy')`

But, I want to use it in memmap mode. So this fails

```
np.load('data.dat.npy',mmap_mode='r')
```

`ValueError: Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.`

And this gives weird encoding

```
np.memmap('data.dat.npy',  mode='r',dtype=[('foo','S40'), 
  ('bar', 'S40'), ('baz', 'S40'), 
  ('buzz', 'S40')
  ])
```

```
 (b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00bar', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00baz', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00buz', b'z\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00foo')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = build_numpy_array()
```

is a (200,) structured array.

to load:

```
In [152]: np.save('data.dat', {'data': data})
```

I have to use `allow_pickle`:

```
In [157]: x=np.load('data.dat.npy',allow_pickle=True)
```

`x` is () shaped object array.  That is `x.item()` is a dictionary, containing the array as an element value.

The problem lies with the save - it's saving a dictionary.

---

```
In [161]: np.save('data.dat', data)                                             
In [162]: x=np.load('data.dat.npy')                                             
In [163]: x.shape                                                               
Out[163]: (200,)
```

now

```
In [165]: r = np.load('data.dat.npy',mmap_mode='r')                             
In [166]: r                                                                     
Out[166]: 
memmap([(b'foo', b'bar', b'baz', b'buzz'),
        (b'foo', b'bar', b'baz', b'buzz'),
        (b'foo', b'bar', b'baz', b'buzz'),
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see the issue. But is the load happening in memory map mode?

Comment: Apparently memory map mode cannot handle the object dtype, the pickle.  But it works if we simply save `data`, rather than a dictionary containing `data`.  The dictionary works with:  `np.savez('data.dat', **{'data': data})` (but that's a zip archive).